# How to redirect in the same Account Detail page after uploaded file sucessfully

Tags: apex, visualforce

**Page**

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="FileUploadController">
<apex:sectionHeader title="Account" subtitle="Account Attachments"/>

<apex:form >
<apex:pageMessages />
<apex:pageBlock title="Upload a File">

<apex:pageBlockButtons >
<apex:commandButton action="{!upload}" value="Attach"/> 
</apex:pageBlockButtons>

<apex:pageBlockSection showHeader="false" columns="2" id="block1">


<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
<apex:outputLabel value="File" for="file"/>
<apex:inputFile value="{!document.body}" filename="{!document.name}" id="file"/>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>


</apex:pageBlockSection>

</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
public with sharing class FileUploadController { 
    public FileUploadController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

    }


    public Attachment document { 
    get { 
        if (document == null) 
        document = new Attachment(); 
    return document; 
    } 
   set; 
} 
public PageReference upload() {

   document.OwnerId = UserInfo.getUserId();
   document.ParentId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id'); // the record the file is attached to
   document.IsPrivate = true;
//document.AuthorId = UserInfo.getUserId(); 
//document.FolderId = UserInfo.getUserId(); // put it in running user's folder 
try { 
insert document;
} catch (DMLException e) { 
ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Error uploading file')); 
return null; 
} finally { 
document.body = null; 
document = new Attachment(); 
} 
ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.INFO,'File uploaded successfully')); 
return null; 
} 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its simple. if you are coming from account detail page then get Account Id in a variable and redirect that using `Pagereference` method.

```
public Id accountId;
public FileUploadController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
          accountId = controller.getId();
}

public PageReference upload() {

// your code here
if(accountId != null)
   return new Pagereference('/'+accountId );
return  new Pagereference('/001');

}
```